# Getting only unique values within a category in Kusto Query Language (Azure Monitor Logs)

Tags: azure, distinct-values, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have data in this format :

```
Category Session_ID  Step_Name

  A         100        1
  A         100        2 
  A         200        1
  A         200        1    <--
  A         200        1    <--
  A         200        2
  B         300        1
  B         300        1    <--
```

I need to remove the duplicate values of step names **within each Session_ID**. For example in ID = 200, there are three '1's which need to be changed to one '1', so the final data looks like :

```
Category Session_ID  Step_Name

  A         100        1
  A         100        2 
  A         200        1
  A         200        2
  B         300        1
```

Comment: Maybe Distinct is working for: `| distinct Session_ID, Step_Name`

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks. Can you put this as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [distinct operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/distinctoperator) in your case:

```
your_table
| distinct Category, Session_ID, Step_Name
```

then you can get the expected output like below, it works at my side:

```
Category Session_ID  Step_Name

  A         100        1
  A         100        2 
  A         200        1
  A         200        2
  B         300        1
```

And for your question in the comment, if you use the above query, the record like "A 100 1" would consider as one entity, and only if there are 2 or more **exact same** record like "A 100 1" would remain only 1 record if using distinct.

And if there is another record like "B 100 1", then the both 2 records "A 100 1" and "B 100 1" would remain.

Comment: If we have a Timestamp column instead of Category, how do we proceed in that case? - considering repeat steps within a session ID will have different timestamps and will be considered as unique.

Comment: If you have a Timestamp column instead of Category, then what's your expected result?

Comment: The repeated step with the latest timestamp should remain (within session_id) and the earlier repeated steps should be removed. (the step with the second arrow should remain and the step with the first arrow must be removed)

Comment: @user75252, could you please post a new issue about that? and provide the link when it's done :).

Comment: Sure, I will do that.

Comment: This a more expanded question :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58519476/date-time-difference-within-a-column-in-azure-monitor-logs-kusto-query-language

Comment: @user75252, I'll look into this issue later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201310/discussion-between-user75252-and-ivan-yang).