# Date time difference within a column in Azure Monitor Logs (Kusto Query Language)

Tags: azure, datetime, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have clickstream data in Azure Monitor Logs in this format:

```
       Timestamp             Category  Session_ID    Step_Name
10/22/2019, 9:28:14.868 AM      A        ++9Ti        step 1    
10/22/2019, 9:28:18.034 AM      A        ++9Ti        step 2    
10/22/2019, 9:28:22.487 AM      A        ++9Ti        step 3
10/23/2019, 7:02:02.527 AM      B        ++MoY        step 1    
10/23/2019, 7:02:09.244 AM      B        ++MoY        step 2    
10/23/2019, 7:02:21.156 AM      B        ++MoY        step 3        <-- 
10/23/2019, 7:02:27.195 AM      B        ++MoY        step 3        <--
10/23/2019, 7:15:13.544 AM      A        ++0a3        step 1    
10/23/2019, 7:15:35.438 AM      A        ++0a3        step 2
```

I need to get the mean time that a consumer spends on each step in a Category

Also, when steps are repeated (like step 3 in session_ID = '++MoY'), we need to take the latest timestamp while calculating the mean.

Example : Mean time spent on step 2 in category A is (3.166 + 21.894)/2 =  12.53 seconds. (Note : timestamp gives time at which step is completed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like the following

a) using `arg_max()` to take the latest by step/category

b) using `prev()` after `order by` to calculate the duration for each step

```
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, Category:string, Session_ID:string, Step_Name:string)
[
    datetime(10/22/2019, 9:28:14.868 AM), 'A', '++9Ti', 'step 1',
    datetime(10/22/2019, 9:28:18.034 AM), 'A', '++9Ti', 'step 2',
    datetime(10/22/2019, 9:28:22.487 AM), 'A', '++9Ti', 'step 3',
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:02:02.527 AM), 'B', '++MoY', 'step 1',
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:02:09.244 AM), 'B', '++MoY', 'step 2',
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:02:21.156 AM), 'B', '++MoY', 'step 3',
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:02:27.195 AM), 'B', '++MoY', 'step 3',
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:15:13.544 AM), 'A', '++0a3', 'step 1',
    datetime(10/23/2019, 7:15:35.438 AM), 'A', '++0a3', 'step 2',
]
| summarize arg_max(Timestamp, *) by Step_Name, Session_ID
| order by Session_ID asc, Timestamp asc
| extend duration = iff(Session_ID == prev(Session_ID), Timestamp - prev(Timestamp), 0s)
| summarize avg(duration) by Step_Name, Category
| where Step_Name == "step 2" and Category == "A"
```

Comment: Works like a charm thank you. I have a doubt, I tried to pivot the table this way :
```|distinct timestamp, Category, session_ID, Step_Name
    |evaluate pivot(Step_Name, max(timestamp))```
But I am not able to do further operations on these pivot columns. Is there a way to operate on pivot columns or is that a limitation in Azure?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to do further operations..."? Could you perhaps add information about what you tried to do, what was the expected result, and what was the actual result?

Comment: Operations like subtraction : ```| extend Step_2 Duration = Step 1 - Step 2 ```
The new column names ( which are the step names) do not seem to be recognized as proper column names. Another operation is sorting these new columns ...

Comment: entity names can't have whitespaces in them, unless the entity name is properly escaped. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/schema-entities/entity-names#identifier-quoting. in this case, you should use `| extend ['Step_2 Duration'] = ['step 1'] - ['step 2']`